# Write php array data for rows that are selected by a checkbox to a file

Tags: php, arrays, post, checkbox

I wrote this to display data from a csv file. When a user selects a checkbox, I need all the data inside that row to be written to a file.  I'm confused as to how to send the array data.

```
<form action="SAP_Conversion.php" method="POST" id="submit_to_XML">

<?
$row = 1;
 $records[0] = 1;
  if (($handle = fopen("upload/Akron.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
     while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
         $num = count($data);
         $records[] = $data;
         echo "<div id=\"row\">
             <div id=\"num\">" .$row. "</div>
              <div class=\"field\">
                  <input name=\"checkbox" . $row . "\" type=\"checkbox\" value=\"$row\" />
              </div>";
         $row++;
         for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
             echo "<div class=\"field\">" . $data[$c] . "</div>";
         }
         echo "</div>";
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To send an array add [] to the name of the element. An actual numerical value is optional. So take what you have and change

```
echo "<div id=\"row\"><div id=\"num\">" .$row. "</div>
    <div class=\"field\"><input name=\"checkbox" . $row . "\" type=\"checkbox\" value=\"$row\" /></div>";
```

to

```
 echo "<div id=\"row\"><div id=\"num\">" .$row. "</div>
    <div class=\"field\"><input name=\"checkbox[" . $row . "]\" type=\"checkbox\" value=\"$row\" /></div>";
```

Then in PHP `$_POST['checkbox']` will be an array after you submit the form.

Comment: I am mainly concerned with the data that is printed out by $data[$c] = this is an array that I need passed.
Once a user selects a checkbox, I need the corresponding array row to be printed at submit.

Answer (score 1):

I rewrote your script, because I find it unclean and hard to read.

```
$fileHandle = fopen("upload/Akron.csv", "r");
$records    = array();
$markup     = '';

if ($fileHandle)
{
    while ($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ","))
    {
        $records[] = $row;
    }

    foreach ($records AS $key => $record)
    {
        $countFields = count($record);

        $markup =
        '<div id="row">
            <div id="num">' . $key . '</div>
            <div class="field">
                <input name="rows[]" type="checkbox" value="' . $key . '" />
            </div>';

        for ($c=0; $c < $countFields; $c++) 
        {
            $markup .=
            '<div class="field">
                ' . $record[$c] . 
            '</div>';
        }

    $markup .= '</div>';
    }

    fclose($handle);
    echo $markup;
}
```

Now for the solution of your problem, as I understand it.
Using my version of the script you will end up with a neat $records array and a $_POST['rows'] array containing all the $record keys requested (checked) by the user.

You can now get the needed data easily from the $records array.

Example:

```
foreach ($_POST['rows'] AS $key)
{
    $selectedRecords[] = $records[$key];
}
```